# How do I add vertical colored ribbons to a chart with xts?

Tags: r, charts, plot, time-series, xts

I have a `xts` object from a quite long daily time series. I plotted a line chart.

Now I want to add vertical colored ribbons, maybe to visually detect some seasonality.

How do I color each quarter of the year in a specific color? (eg, all Q1 = blue, Q2 = green, Q3 = orange, Q4 = mauve)

Below is a chart quite similar to what I am after, but in this case 1 year over 2 is colored in grey.

[image: chart]

Comment: Provide sample data and code.

Answer (score 1):

Without much information to go on, here's a makeshift version using base R and the `mtcars` data set.

You can use the `rect` function to plot alternating colored rectangles.  The trick is to make the rectangles a bit longer than the range of the y values, and then `box` the plot again at the end to get clean lines.  The colors used here are taken from the loop values (plus 4).

Playing around with the code on this one is really the best way to see how it works.

```
> data(mtcars)
> plot(mtcars$mpg, type = 'n')
> sapply(seq(0, 30, 10), function(x) rect(x, 0, x+5, 35, col = x+4))
> lines(mtcars$mpg)
> box()
```

[image]